# Error when accessing array - stack around the variable 'scores' was corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am new to C++ and have written some code in which I'm getting the following error:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'scores' was corrupted

What is causing this error?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream> // Enables cout and endl
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;
int getInput();

int main()
{
    int scores[5];
    int i;
    int j;
    int numberOfScores;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) // Sets all 5 elements of the array to zero
    {
        scores[i] = 0;
    }

    cout << "How many scores do you have to enter?\n" << endl;
    cin >> numberOfScores;


    for (j = 0; j < numberOfScores; j++) // Gather test scores and increases each array index as that score is entered
    {
        scores[getInput()] ++;
    }

    cout << "The number of zeros: " << scores[0] << endl;
    cout << "The number of ones: " << scores[1] << endl;
    cout << "The number of twos: " << scores[2] << endl;
    cout << "The number of threes: " << scores[3] << endl;
    cout << "The number of fours: " << scores[4] << endl;
    cout << "The number of fives: " << scores[5] << endl;


    return 0;
}

int getInput()
{
    int enteredScore;
    cout << "Enter the test scores one at a time.\n";
    cout << "The range of scores is 0 to 5.\n";
    cin >> enteredScore;

    if (enteredScore >= 0 && enteredScore <= 5)
    {
        return enteredScore;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error!  The range of scores is 0 to 5.\n";
        cout << "Enter the test scores one at a time.\n";
        cin >> enteredScore;
        return enteredScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)` should be `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)`, otherwise it will access scores[5], which is off by one due to 0 based indexing ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, is valid, that's the 5 elements you requested storage for ).

Comment: Debug before asking here please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this declaration:

```
int scores[5];
```

Is incorrect. This creates an array with 5 numbers in it, indices from `scores[0-4]`, however, you constantly refer to `score[5]`, the *sixth* element of the array throughout your program. I recommend changing to

```
int scores[6];
```

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry about not debugging first - honestly, I don't know how to do that yet.  I tried (in Visual Studio), but nothing happened.  Sorry about that.  Anyway, int scores[6] did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @sparky Note, that isn't sufficient by itself to fix the problem, as you are also not validating the user input properly.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**

You are accessing your array out of bounds in several places.

Here you loop through 6 elements when you only have 5:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) // Loops through 6 elements
    {
        scores[i] = 0;
    }
```

Here you call `getInput()` and use the return value as the index:

```
scores[getInput()] ++;
```

However, the first half of the function accepts inputs from the user in the range 0 to 5, thus allowing access to 6 elements:

```
if (enteredScore >= 0 && enteredScore <= 5)
```

It gets even worse if the user enters a number outside that range, as they are then given a second opportunity to enter a number, only this time there is no validation and any number they enter is accepted:

```
cin >> enteredScore;
return enteredScore;
```

Finally, you again attempt to access a 6th element here:

```
cout << "The number of fives: " << scores[5] << endl;
```

**Solution:**

First, you need to do one of two things:

- Change the `for` loop, `if` statement, and `cout` statements so that they do not access index 5

or:

- Create the array so that it has 6 elements: `int scores[6];`

Secondly, you need to fix the bug in your `getInput()` function so that it validates the input properly. You could try this for example:

```
int getInput()
{
    int enteredScore;
    cout << "Enter the test scores one at a time.\n";
    cout << "The range of scores is 0 to 4.\n";
    cin >> enteredScore;

    while (enteredScore < 0 || enteredScore > 4)
    {
        cout << "Error!  The range of scores is 0 to 4.\n";
        cout << "Enter the test scores one at a time.\n";
        cin >> enteredScore;
    }
    return enteredScore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in

```
 cout << "The number of fives: " << scores[5] << endl;
```

Your array is of size 5 but you are accessing the 6th element.

Same with  `for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)` should be `i < 5`.

Comment: He is accessing index 5 actually